Creating SQL Pivot Query by using field value for datapoint list
Our corporate GIS is being upgraded and certain SQL queries need to be simplified to work. We can't call stored procedures/run dynamic queries or create temporary tables in these queries once we upgrade. The below query creates a pivot table using a dynamic query and I cannot figure out a workaround. It outputs the number of common species within certain cells.
declare @species varchar(20) = 'BIRDS'

declare @cols varchar(max), @pivot varchar(max) set @cols = (select STUFF((SELECT ','+ 
quotename(Common_name) FROM Fauna_Species WHERE Species_Type = @species and cell_ref = 
'@mapkey' ORDER BY Common_Name FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')) set @pivot = ' SELECT ' + @cols + 
'FROM  (SELECT Common_nam, count(*) count FROM Fauna_Data_2012 WHERE Species_Ty = 
'''+@species+''' and cell_ref = ''' + '@mapkey' + ''' GROUP BY Common_nam)  AS DP PIVOT 
(MIN([count]) FOR Common_nam IN ('+@cols+' )) AS P;'
exec (@pivot)


As a test I have created a table that holds the Species, Cell Reference and I've used STUFF to put all Common_Names for that cell into one field, to be used in the pivot query.
INSERT INTO GIS_Fauna_Fields (Species, CellRef, Common_Name)
SELECT DISTINCT Species_ty, cell_ref, STUFF((SELECT ','+quotename(Common_name)
FROM Fauna_Species f WHERE Species_Type =
Species_ty and f.cell_ref = f2012.cell_ref GROUP BY Common_Name ORDER
BY Common_Name FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') FROM Fauna_Data_2012 f2012


Then every time the user in our GIS clicks on a fauna cell the
background query would look something like the below.
DECLARE @cols varchar(max) set @cols = (SELECT Common_Name FROM
GIS_Fauna_Fields WHERE Species = 'BIRDS' and cellref = '150D4') --cellref will be a variable in the GIS configuration

-- pivots results with count
SELECT @cols FROM (SELECT Common_Nam, count(*) [count] FROM Fauna_Data_2012  WHERE Species_Ty = 'BIRDS' and
cell_ref = '150D4' GROUP BY Common_nam)  AS DP PIVOT (MIN([count]) FOR
Common_nam IN (Common_Name)) AS P;

However, I can't specify the datapoints with a variable so I am using Common_Name. The data will differ for each cell ref but will look something like this
[Common Froglet],[Southern Brown Tree Frog],[Verreauxs Tree Frog]

I am not getting the desired results. I need the column name (Common_Name) containing the count, but I get a no-name column containing the Common_Name instead.
Is there a way around this without dynamic queries?

It looks like what I'm asking might not be possible so I've compromised with an export tool that includes the counts of common_name by species for the selected cell.
